# <input type='number'> is auto incrementing. Bug?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I think I have found a bug concerning the following binding: `<input type='number'>` when using a controller

**html:**

...
    
    {ctrl.i}}
    ...

**dart:**

...
    @NgController(...)
    class AController {
      int i = 5;
    }
    ...

When one modifies the input field, then there is an infinite loop (auto increment or auto decrement)

Note that this problem does not happen when using no-scope like in:

```
...
<input type="number" ng-model="i">
{{i}}
...
```

Is that a bug? Is there a way to use `<input type='number'>`?

Comment: Changes have been implemented to the code handling inputs of type number. Do you still see this problem?  If so, could you share more of you HTML so that I can understand the context?

Answer (score 0):

I tried it but couldn't get it to work with int but works fine with double `class ACController { double i = 5.0; }`.

```
type 'double' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'value'.
```

**EDIT**
Same error in Angular '0.9.9' works only with double.

Answer (score 0):

There may have been a bug, but it appears to be fixed now.

I verified that this use cases work in AngularDart 0.9.10.