# html5 input type number is auto incrementing in angular bootstrap?

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap

hi i'm using [angular bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) . when i single click on input element (where input type is number) .. the value auto increments to +1. For ex. if the value is 1 and then i click on increment , it increments to 3 ..same is happening with the decrement operation.

i have tried setting step property in html5, but it doesn't work.
i don't know if this is a bug or other problem

Btw , my version is ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0

there's another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20452207/input-type-number-is-auto-incrementing-bug) at stackoverflow  but a little different

thanks for ur suggestions !!